# How to pass values to a Custom Resolver in Automapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I need to pass values to my Custom Resolver. The values change, so I can't hard code them in my register static class. How can I achieve this?

```
// Called from global.asa page
   public static void Register()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Task, TaskTableViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.DueDate,
                                                               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DueDateResolver>().ConstructedBy(() => new DueDateResolver(dateFormatString)));
```

}

Comment: [.ForMember(dest => dest.SomePropA, opt=> opt.ResolveUsing<MyResolver>().FromMember(src => src.propA))][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368525/automapper-using-the-structure-returned-by-a-custom-resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked about this on another board and was told it isn't possible to do in this version.