# How to pass value to a custom ValueResolver?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm struggling with the format for passing in a value to a custom ValueResolver. I am basically trying to convert an Int to and Object based on my ViewModel. However, I cannot get it to pass it the value to my ValueResolver

I have the following Custom ValueResolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<CreateContainerViewModel, Container>
{ 
    private int id = 0;

    public CustomResolver(int? sourceId)
    {
        if(sourceId.HasValue)
            id = sourceId.Value;
    }
    protected override Container ResolveCore(CreateContainerViewModel source)
    {
        if (id == 0) return null;
        else
        {
            ISession _session = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISessionFactory>().GetCurrentSession();
            return _session.Get<Container>(id);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when I create the map using a hard coded int like the following code

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CreateContainerViewModel, Container>()
.ForMember(a => a.CurrentContainer, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => new CustomResolver(33)));
```

but it isn't working (throwing mapping exception) when I try and get the value from my viewmodel

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CreateContainerViewModel, Container>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CurrentContainer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new CustomResolver(src.CurrentContainerId)));
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of the correct syntax for passing in a value to a custom ValueResolver?

Thanks

UPDATE:

basically trying to write something like this:

```
  public class IdToObjectResolver<T> : ValueResolver<int, T> where T : class
{ 
    private ISession _session;
    private int id;
    public IdToObjectResolver(Nullable<int> sourceId)
    {
        _session = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISessionFactory>().GetCurrentSession();
        if(sourceId.HasValue)
            id = sourceId.Value;
    }

    protected override T ResolveCore(int source)
    {
        return _session.Get<T>(source);
    }
}
```

This code doesnt currently make sense, but just trying to get a way of passing in the int...

Comment: This page http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers says Customizing the source value supplied to the resolver - Coming soon :)

Comment: [.ForMember(dest => dest.SomePropA, opt=> opt.ResolveUsing<MyResolver>().FromMember(src => src.propA))][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368525/automapper-using-the-structure-returned-by-a-custom-resolver

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I think that you might be over complicating the ValueResolver a bit.  As you can see, the entire `CreateContainerViewModel` class is send in the `ResolveCore` method in the ValueResolver.  That will be the entire source object with values.

Therefore, you should be able to pull the id value from the source object by using this mapping: `opt.ResolveUsing(src => new CustomResolver())`. (with no constructor arg).

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

My Test:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<CreateContainerViewModel, Container>()
                .ForMember(a => a.CurrentContainer, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());


            var source = new CreateContainerViewModel()
            {
                ID = 3
            };

            var destination = new Container();

            Mapper.Map(source, destination);

            Assert.AreEqual(destination.CurrentContainer.ID, 3);

        }
```

CustomResolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<CreateContainerViewModel, Container>
{
    protected override Container ResolveCore(CreateContainerViewModel source)
    {

            return new Container() { ID = source.ID };  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dtryon. I am actually trying to develop a more generic solution for resolving foreign key id fields into the objects in my domain. Whilst the solution posted will work, i would have to create new custom resolvers for every foreign key object - i was hoping to be able to develop a generic solution that allows me to pass in the id from properties of the object being mapped

Comment: I have updated my original question with an example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Ok, I think I must of misunderstood.  However, even in the new example, which object is the `sourceId` coming from? Source object or destination object or neither?

Comment: The id would come from the source object, the idea being that it sets a property in the destination object via way of an nhibernate call.. thanks

Comment: Got it.  I'm not sure this is what Jimmy is saying is Coming soon... I think he means a more granular fluent way to right the ValueResolver (so you don't have to write another class).  You might be bordering on asking a mapping tool to do the job of a repository.  Might be possible, but you are working against what AutoMapper was built to do (bind a mapping between two known types).

Comment: yeah i thought this might be the case.. at the moment i am using automapper plus some additional logic to then bring back the foreign key objects in a 'map' method. this is because i am using mvc viewmodels that are returned in a POST which then need to update or merge with the existing database

Comment: Usually, in the design you have described, you would have view model and model objects that largely have the same properties.  You would make the view model to the model, validate and then update from the model object.  Would this not work in your case?

Comment: thats exactly what im doing now... but my viewmodel has foreign key id properties (i.e. ViewModelObject.UserId) and my domain has objects (i.e. DomainObject.User), so I am currently automapping the two, then doing this: DomainObject.User = session.Load<User>(ViewModelObject.UserId); - i was just wondering if there was a way of eliminating the extra step. (might not be worth the effort though :) )... anyway thanks for your help it's appreciated

Comment: I see, makes sense.  I wonder if you could map ViewModelObject.UserId to DomainObject.User.Id?  If you are not changing any User properties, the ORM might wire everything up.  Anyway, hope you find the right solution. :)